# Хеш ветки или хеш коммита

Tags: java, git, gitlab

Столкнулся с задачей вывода текущей версии приложения, расположенного в репозитории git. Совпадает ли хеш ветки master с хешем последнего коммита в эту ветку? Это одно и тоже или нет?

Comment: У веток в Git нет хэшей. Это просто именованные ссылки на какую-либо фиксацию из репозитория.

Comment: Обычно версию хранят в лейблах гита, они вроде для этого и существуют. Также если сборка проходит мавеном, то версию приложения можно брать из `pom.xml`

Comment: mymedia, фиксация это и есть последний коммит?

Comment: второй вопрос удалён: во-первых, в одном вопросе должен быть один вопрос, во-вторых, второй вопрос задан в форме опросника. попробуйте сформулировать его более корректно и задать отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Совпадает ли хеш ветки master с хешем последнего коммита в эту ветку? Это одно и тоже или нет?

«хэша ветки» не существует в природе. ветка (branch) в программе *git* — это плавающий указатель на (один) коммит.

собственно «содержимым» ветки и является хэш коммита, последнего в последовательности коммитов, связанных друг с другом благодаря тому, что каждый коммит (кроме самого первого) содержит хэш «родительского» коммита (а некоторые коммиты, т.н. «коммиты слияния», имеют и более одного «предка»).